# Returning a length from a list of divs, with exceptions to its children not having a certain attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, traversal

I have a list of divs that I need to traverse to return a particular length.  I must add up all the total amount of divs that have active images.  Inactive images are denoted by an `alt= "missing"`.  I need this particular length size for an ajax interactions.

### Question

**How can I get the length of parent divs, that do NOT have children elements with a alt tag  value of missing?** *(sorry for the verbosity in selectors)*

---

---

**HTML**

```
 <div class="project-img-container">
        <div class="modal-image-0">
            <img alt="Florence" class="featured" src="/system/works/avatars/000/000/034/medium/florence.jpg?1374131286">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-image-1">
            <img alt="Nexus" class="featured" src="/system/works/avatar_bs/000/000/034/medium/nexus.jpg?1374131286">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-image-2">
            <img alt="Missing" class="featured" src="/images/medium/missing.png">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-image-3">
            <img alt="Missing" class="featured" src="/images/medium/missing.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

**Jquery** *success: postImgModal*

```
postImgModal = function(data, status) {
  var activeChildren, children, imgVal;
  imgVal = [];

  children = $(data).find('.project-img-container').children();

  /*
     children will return an object list of all divs (which in this case = 4) now I must remove the parent tags that have children img tags that have alt tag's value = "missing." 

     Lets call this var activeChildren

  */

  $.each(activeChildren, function(i, child) {
    imgVal[i] = child;
    console.log(imgVal[i]);
    return imgVal[i];
  });

  /*this loop should return a length of 2.  Opposed to before which was 4. This is because there were 2 missing alt tags above in this example html.*/

}
```

The final output should be a length of 2 for var activeChildren = 2;  and imgVal should return just these two divs

```
<div class="modal-image-0">
    <img alt="Florence" class="featured" src="/system/works/avatars/000/000/034/medium/florence.jpg?1374131286">
</div>
<div class="modal-image-1">
    <img alt="Nexus" class="featured" src="/system/works/avatar_bs/000/000/034/medium/nexus.jpg?1374131286">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(data).find('.project-img-container').children().filter(function() {
    return !$(this).find('[alt="Missing"]').length;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ8Mw/)

or just:

```
$(data).find('.project-img-container').children(':has([alt!="Missing"])');
```

Comment: @Sushanth-- just noticed!

Comment: Perfect @adeneo never heard of this filter() but it makes perfect sense thanks so much! marking right asap

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work

```
$('div > img:not([alt="Missing"])').length;
```

Or This one looks for featured images.

```
$('div > img.featured:not([alt="Missing"])').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery property value is case sensitive so you have to make sure it's in the right case:

```
$(".project-img-container").find("img:not([alt='Missing'])")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery selectors to meet your needs. Below expression should serve the purpose.

```
$('div.project-img-container').find('img[alt!="Missing"]').parent();
```